# Deriving an infinite product from an infinite summation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $m_i$ be some positive integer and let $p$ be a probability.

How can I derive $\prod_{i=1}^\infty(1-p^{x+i})^{m_i}=0$ if I know $\sum_{i=1}^\infty (m_ip^i)=\infty$?

Take the natural log on the infinte product, we have $\ln\prod_{i=1}^\infty(1-p^{x+i})^{m_i} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \ln(1-p^{x+i})^{m_i}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (m_i\ln(1-p^{x+i}))$

I don't know how to continue on the derivation. Can someone help me?

Comment: Hint: $\ln (1-p) \leq -p$ .

Answer (score 2):

The proposition is false. Consider the case $m_i = -2^i$, $p = 1/2$. Then clearly $\sum_{i=1}^\infty (m_ip^i) = -\infty$, but each $(1-p^i)^{m_i} > 1$, so the product certainly doesn't converge to 0.

Edit: Jacky edited the problem so that the proposition is true.

Comment: $m_i$ is just some constant real numbers for example, $m_1 = 4, m_2 = 8, m_3 = 1...$

Comment: @jacky Yes and you asked how to show that for any such choice of constant real numbers, the proposition holds. I gave an example of a choice of constant real numbers such that the proposition does not hold, so the proposition is false.

Comment: I meant $m_i$ is a positive integer. Forgot to mention it.

Comment: In that case all terms in the sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty (m_i p^i)$ are positive, so it cannot possibly diverge to $-\infty$. Did you also mean for the sum to equal positive $\infty$ instead of negative $\infty$?

Comment: It's the positive $\infty$. My mistake. Thanks.